# How to write Dockerfile to spin up substrate node template

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker

How to write Dockerfile to spin up substrate node template, unit tests and/or integration tests, e2e tests, etc? Someone please suggest some resources.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hack-ink/slothunter/blob/main/test/guide.md

Here is my test setup:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

COPY\
  data/polkadot\
  data/rococo.json.fork-off\
  ./

RUN chmod u+x polkadot

ENTRYPOINT ./polkadot --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods unsafe --tmp --chain rococo.json.fork-off --alice
```

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/db/postgres:/db/postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: squid-archive

  node:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9944:9944"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db/node:/db/node

  ingest:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - node
    restart: on-failure
    image: subsquid/substrate-ingest:firesquid
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    command:
      [
        "-e",
        "ws://host.docker.internal:9944",
        "--out",
        "postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/squid-archive"
      ]

  gateway:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: subsquid/substrate-gateway:firesquid
    environment:
      RUST_LOG: "substrate_gateway=info,actix_server=info"
    command:
      [
        "--database-url",
        "postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/squid-archive",
        "--database-max-connections",
        "3"
      ]
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  explorer:
    image: subsquid/substrate-explorer:firesquid
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: "5432"
      DB_NAME: "squid-archive"
      DB_USER: "postgres"
      DB_PASS: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```